# iFrame contents not loading/working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

The link below works fine in FireFox and Chrome, however when try to open it in IE nothing seems to work or load.

I am loading the whole website inside of the iFrame. I initial analysis is it could be jQuery as there is no jquery reference in the iFrame.

Can the  run on all browsers.

http://hitin.net/projects/aurion/aurion.html

I have tested it on IE9

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhdMF/

```
<body>
<div id="content">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.auriongroup.com/">
    &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;
</iframe>
</div>
```

```
body, html
        {
            margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
        }
        #content
        {
            position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0;height:100%;
        }
```

Update:
My intention is to load the website inside the iFrame and host the iFrame page on a different domain then auriongroup.com

Regards,

Hitin

Comment: Well it might help if you told us what vERSIONS of internet explorer are actually affected and be a little more specific on "nothing seems to work or load".  What is supposed to happen exactly?  Post your code and put it in a jsfiddle for us

Comment: This issue is not because of the IFRAME. The original web is not IE friendly. I mean, I open "www.auriongroup.com/" directly in IE8, the issue is still there. I guess the jquery flippy used some attributes just supported by modern browsers like FF and Chrome.

Comment: i tried <iframe src='http://hitin.net/projects/aurion/aurion.htmlhttp://hitin.net/projects/aurion/aurion.html' ></iframe> this iframe in ie9 and it worked for me!!! Can you be more specific, i mean show your code atleast

Comment: @sanjeev hi, I agree that the poster need to provide the detail of the failure. On the other hand, I've tested the site, you can reproduce this issue under IE8 :)

Comment: I have added the code. All I am trying to do is to get the site opened inside iframe. Which works just fine in firefox and chrome but IE9.

Answer (score 0):

I found some introduction from [here](http://guilhemmarty.com/flippy/)
It says,

> Cross browser ?
>   The Flippy plugin works fine for every modern web browser except Internet Explorer 8 and before (of course…). In this demo I used the excanvas.js file to allow the use of canvas in older IE versions. You can find it here.

So the issue happens because IE8 and prior versions doesn't support canvas. You can try excanvas.js mentioned by the author.

Comment: I will try this out and see how it works for IE. Thanks Merlin :)

Comment: I have implemented it, still doesnt seem to work on IE. you can try the url www.auriongroup.com (it host the iFrame page now)